# $\Pi_{1}^{k}(p_{j} - 1) \mid (\Pi_{1}^{k}p_{j} - 1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Do there exist an integer $k \geq 2$ and distinct odd primes $p_{1}, \dots, p_{k}$
such that
$$\Pi_{1}^{k}(p_{j}-1) \mid (\Pi_{1}^{k}p_{j} - 1)$$

Comment: Please note that it is my personal ignorance (forgetting to assume the primes to be distinct) that makes the answer appeared.

Comment: Oh I have found that it turns out this is an unsolved problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the primes do not need to be distinct, then

$$ ( 3 - 1) \times (3-1) \mid ( 3 \times 3 -1 ) $$

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry to forget to impose distinctness.